# What are the naming conventions for nested routes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

(This question is related to this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/IDiMu/1/))

I have the following router configuration:

```
App.Router.map(function() {

    this.resource('profile', function () {
        this.route('user');
        this.route('userEdit');
        this.route('company');
        this.route('companyEdit');
        this.resource('products', function () {
            this.route('index');
            this.route('show',   { path: '/:product_id/show' });
        });
    });

});
```

With this, ember data expects the following controllers:

- ProfileIndexController
- ProfileUserController
- ProfileUserEditController
- ProfileCompanyController
- ProfileCompanyEditController

The following routes:

- ProfileRoute
- ProfileIndexRoute
- ProfileUserRoute
- ProfileUserEditRoute
- ProfileCompanyRoute
- ProfileCompanyEditRoute

And the following templates:

- index
- profile
- profile/index
- profile/user
- profile/userEdit
- profile/company
- profile/companyEdit

But I am unable to address the nested resource profile/products. I was expecting the controllers at:

- ProfileProductsController
- ProfileProductsIndexController
- ProfileProductsShowController

The routes at:

- ProfileProductsIndexRoute
- ProfileProductsShowRoute

And the templates at:

- profile/products
- profile/products/index

Instead, by following the link to `#/profile/products/index`, ember is generating the following objects:

```
generated -> route:products Object {fullName: "route:products"}
generated -> route:products.index Object {fullName: "route:products.index"}
generated -> controller:products Object {fullName: "controller:products"}
Could not find "products" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:products"}
generated -> controller:products.index Object {fullName: "controller:products.index"}
Could not find "products.index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:products.index"}
Transitioned into 'profile.products.index
```

Which is unexpected for me: the products are nested within the profile! I could of course change my controllers / routes / templates, but I would like to understand what is going on. The problem that I see is that a top level "products" will conflict with the nested "profile/products".

How does ember handle nested resources, regarding the generation of objects names (routes / views / templates / controllers). Where is this documented? (specifically for nested resources!)

Answer (score 5):

I know you've answered your own question, but I might be able to provide more insight.

Check [this awesome article](http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/02/01/ember-dot-js-router-and-template-naming-convention/) out. It's an awesome explanation of nested resources and routes in Ember.

To summarize, any time you call `this.resource()` (in your case `this.resource('products')` you are creating a new namespace, *even when the call itself is nested.*

This means that the nested call to `resource` will generate a `ProductsController`, not `ProfileProductsController`, as well as a `ProductsView` (and `products` template) rather than a `ProfileProductsView`. The associated template will require an `{{outlet}}` to render it's children in.

Furthermore, `this.resource('products')` will create a `ProductsIndexController` (and a `products.index` template), so you can go ahead and remove your nested `this.route('index')` call from the projects resource.

Answer (score 0):

After writing this long question, I realize that this is a [documented](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources) feature.

It still is unclear for me what will happen in case there are top-level resources and nested resources called the same. I guess that will cause a conflict. I would say ember is assuming too much here: that there is only one kind of "products", which must not necessarily be the case.